# How do I write an algorithm to find the total number of patterns of the sum of two numbers?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Suppose n =3
Using the numbers 1 and 2, the combinations to get the sum n would be [1,2], [2,1], [1,1,1].  3 combinations.

If n= 2
then the combinations to get the sum n would be [1,1] and [2]. 2 combinations.

How do I write an algorithm to compute the number of combinations of 1 and 2 to get the sum to n?

Comment: I tried looking up some formulas of permutations but I still don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: I would like to work on this, but it will be closed -_- ... add some code

Comment: You can try with a recursive function which subtracts 1 from input untill input is 1 it self, and then creating a permutation of these numbers retuned by these recursive calling.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing seems to be the `Coin-Change Problem` in the `dynamic-programming` category. You can check out these links below to gain a better understanding of them -

[Coin Change Problem - GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)
[Coin Change Problem - Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change)

Since just providing a link is not acceptable, i am posting some of the link's content here to give you an idea -

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of
S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins,
how many ways can we make the change?

The order of coins doesn’t matter.

For example, for N = 4 and S = {1,2,3},
there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}. 
So output should be 4.

For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, 
there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}.
So the output should be 5.

**Optimal Substructure**

To count total number solutions, we can divide all set solutions in two sets.
1) Solutions that do not contain mth coin (or Sm).
2) Solutions that contain at least one Sm.
Let count(S[], m, n) be the function to count the number of solutions,
then it can be written as sum of *count(S[], m-1, n)* and *count(S[], m, n-Sm)*.

Therefore, the problem has optimal substructure property as the problem can be solved using solutions to subproblems.

**Overlapping Subproblems**

Following is a simple recursive implementation of the Coin Change problem. The implementation simply follows the recursive structure mentioned above.

```
// Returns the count of ways we can sum  S[0...m-1] coins to get sum n
int count( int S[], int m, int n )
{
    // If n is 0 then there is 1 solution (do not include any coin)
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    // If n is less than 0 then no solution exists
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;

   // If there are no coins and n is greater than 0, then no solution exist
   if (m <=0 && n >= 1)
       return 0;

   // count is sum of solutions (i) including S[m-1] (ii) excluding S[m-1]
   return count( S, m - 1, n ) + count( S, m, n-S[m-1] );
}
```

If you think and dry run the above code you should be able to grasp the basic idea. I hope this solves your problem.

The above explanation :
*Courtesy - GeeksforGeeks*

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in Mathematics way. The equation is summation of (n-r)Cr where r = 0,1,2,...,n/2 for all n>0

Note that this equation can be further generalize for n>0 and set {1,x} only. Other than this, you should look at the idea provided by @RahulNori

---

n=4

```
[1,1,1,1] - 1 combination (4C0)
[2,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,1,2] - 3 combination (3C1)
[2,2] - 1 combination (2C2)
```

---

n=5

```
[1,1,1,1,1] - 1 combination (5C0)
[2,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1], [1,1,2,1], [1,1,1,2] - 4 combination (4C1)
[2,2,1], [2,1,2], [1,2,2] - 3 combination (3C2)
```

---

n=6

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1] - 1 combination (6C0)
[2,1,1,1,1], [1,2,1,1,1], [1,1,2,1,1], [1,1,1,2,1], [1,1,1,1,2] - 5 combination (5C1)
[2,2,1,1], [2,1,2,1], [1,2,2,1], [2,1,1,2], [1,2,1,2], [1,1,2,2] - 6 combination (4C2)
[2,2,2] - 1 combination (3C3)
```